# Assign a single element of a nettype struct

Tags: system-verilog

The usual assignment style to a Systemverilog net defined by a typedef struct, like

```
typedef struct {
real V;
real I;
real R;
}  SVAstruct;
// resolution function ommitted
nettype SVAstruct SVAnet with res_SVA;
```

is

```
inout SVAnet P;
assign P = '{Vout,0,0};
```

So the assignments are done simultaneously for all elements of the net structure. Assignments like

```
P.R = 100;
```

give an error. Is there any method to do individual assignments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that. Once you create a nettype with a particular data type, each driver needs all fields of type in order to execute its resolution function.

Imagine if you wanted a signal to represent the force on an physical object. A force is a vector quantity that has both magnitude and direction. If each driver on that signal represents a force vector, there is no way to drive a direction without knowing what the magnitude is.

You can create a variable with the same type as a net and then you can make individual assignments to fields of that variable.

```
inout SVAnet P;
...
SVAstruct S
assign P = S;
...
S.R = 100;
```

Comment: While the proposal allows for individual assignments to elements of S, it does not allow to do this for elements of P. 
For example, if there are contributions from other modules to the values of P, these would be overwritten by assign P = S;.
So the "you cannot do that" still holds. - Thx!

Comment: The outputs of those other modules should not be an `SVAnet`, just simple real numbers representing V, I, or R. Then you can combine them together.

Comment: Correct, but in my case unfortunately they are.